# Jinja variables in map.jinja

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

I'm trying to set a dynamic variable in map.jinja but it is not setting correctly.

I have a software version I want to be able to set through a grain and pick it up in the map to dynamically select the directories. I'm using the keyword version like below.

map.jinja

```
{% set version = grains.get('version', '') %}
{% set myapp = salt['grains.filter_by']({
    'RedHat': {
        'sudoers': {
            'name': '/etc/sudoers',
            'text':['appuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /usr/opt/HTTP{{ version }}/bin/apachectl'],
        },
    },
}, merge=salt['pillar.get']('myapp:lookup')) %}
```

And the result is just the jinja template tag included not rendered to the version number...

salt '10.0.1.15' state.show_sls myapp

```
/etc/sudoers:
    ----------
    __env__:
        base
    __sls__:
        myapp.accounts
    file:
        |_
            ----------
            text:
                |_
                    ----------
                    appuser ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /usr/opt/HTTP{{ version }}/bin/apachectl
```

Notice no change to the line.... its not being rendered

My import line:

```
{% from "myapp/map.jinja" import myapp %}
/etc/sudoers:
    file.append:
        - text:
            {% for item in myapp.sudoers.text -%}
            - {{ item }}
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to quote `{{ item }}` in the state file

```
{% from "myapp/map.jinja" import myapp %} /etc/sudoers: file.append: - text: {% for item in myapp.sudoers.text -%} - '{{ item }}' {% endfor %}
```